# Excel Grouping Check if specific parameters and increment

Tags: excel-formula

Looking to create a logic to organize data to specific codes based off naming

Havent been able to create a methodology to do this properly. I think i'm almost there and am attaching a sample.
Proposed Code is the output i'm looking for

[image: 1]

Comment: If your requirement isn't `=4001+[@Column2]`, explain on what logic the values in *Column2* are generated. Also, add the formula(s) you have tried to your post.